# While developing a API wrapper in Python, how should I handle invalid inputs?

Tags: python, wrapper

I am writing a wrapper function for a web API right now and the API expects the date to be input in a particular format (YYYY-MM-DD). I am wondering how to notify the wrapper user if the the input format is incorrect?

My thoughts:

- Let the API itself take care of it and simply return what the API
  returns
  *This takes care of any future changes in the API*
- Write a handler in the wrapper and if the input is incorrect, then
  simply return the HTTP error code 400 (Bad Request).
  *The users often have a restriction of number of API requests per day and this would help them from wasting them because of invalid input.*

**EDIT**
As pointed out in the comments, the decision depends on my take on maintenance. Can you also tell me is the general good practice or should one look at these situations on case by case basis?

Comment: The answer to this depends on whether you're okay with updating the API wrapper whenever the API changes.

Comment: Good point @SimeonVisser I want to keep the wrapper easy to maintain but will of course update the wrapper when the API gets updated.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Why was this put on hold as opinion-based? I know that the term wrapper can be widely interpreted. It does, however, have a *very clear definition*. Putting such questions on hold will further encourage people to use this term meaning a lot of different things. If one would reopen this question, everyone on the Internet would get a straight-forward and (more importantly) correct solution. I thought that this is what SO wants to be about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember:

> A wrapper function is a subroutine in a software library or a computer program whose main purpose is to call a second subroutine or a **system call with little or no additional computation**.

As found on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function).

Therefore I suggest you doing the first thing, letting the API handle it. Whenever I use a wrapper, I only ever want to look at the Documentation of the *actual API*, not the wrapper. It also seems a lot more intuitive to me.

Good luck :)